# Converting existing app to TypeScript. What do I do with a function that was previously checking typeof

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am taking the path of least resistance, as has been advised by many blogs. However, I don't even really know what to do in this situation.

I have a function that looks something like this:

```
function getError(err: any) {
  let errArray = [];

  if (typeof err === "string") {
    errArray.push(err);
  } else if (err.isAxiosError) {
    // ...do stuff
  }

  return errArray;
}
```

As you can see, it can potentially get an error string or axios error object. Can I put two types in the arguments? That seems like the completely wrong thing to do. What should one do in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if your error can either be a `"string"` or some other object, you can tell the compiler that it's a union of the two types:

```js
type SomeOtherObject = {
  isAxiosError: true
};

function getError(err: "string" | SomeOtherObject) {
  let errArray = [];

  if (typeof err === "string") {
    errArray.push(err);
  } else if (err.isAxiosError) {
    // ...do stuff
  }

  return errArray;
}
```